# apache rewrite rules issue for specific pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have problem with my .htaccess redirections. When I type:

```
http://www.domain.com/contact
```

it goes to the index.php and not the contact.php

here's my .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /clients http://clients.domain.com

RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIf Host ^www\. page=www
SetEnvIf Host ^mob\. page=mobile

RewriteBase /
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Wget" bad_bo
#etc ... 
Deny from env=bad_bot

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php 
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php 

rewriterule ^(.*)$ index.php?subdomain=%{ENV:page}&page=$1
```

in my php i get:

```
<?php

print_r($_GET);
Array (
  [subdomain] => www
  [page] => contact.php
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: your missing your final '/'after contact

Comment: @TobyAllen `/?` with the question mark the rule either use / or not

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [NC,QSA,L]

rewriterule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?subdomain=%{ENV:page}&page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I also added the `NC, QSA, L` flags to make sure the last rule `[L]` is executed if match, `[NC]` for non case and `[QSA]` for Query String Append.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your about and contact rules in the following way:

```
RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [L,QSA]
```